# App consistently crashes at different points depending on compiler optimization

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, exc-bad-access, compiler-optimization

My app runs fine if compiler optimization = None [-O0].

Crashes consistently at one point if optimization = Fast [-O, -O1], crashes consistently at a different point if set to -O2, -O3 or -Ofast, and at a different point if set to -Os.

The crashes all happen in the `viewDidLoad` start-up sequence and are always `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

The crashes only happen when running on the iPad1/iOS5.1.1. No crashes on iPad4/iOS7.1, regardless of optimization setting.

It used to be fine, but it broke sometime recently - having rolled back to previously working versions which are now also crashing, it looks like it might be due to Xcode/SDK version.

Am using Xcode 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.8.5. Base SDK = Latest iOS (iOS 7.1); iOS Deployment Target = iOS 5.0.

My question is: based on the above info, what's the best approach to debug from here on? Am a bit stuck.

Edit: here is the crash log using -O3:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x6454f8e3
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x36b78cd8 std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::tie() const + 0
1   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x36b91544 std::ostream::sentry::sentry(std::ostream&) + 20
2   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x36b93b86 std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int) + 22
3   KP v2 Dev                       0x0001817e performerApp::setBankSettingsFromXmlStruct(int) (performerApp.mm:2607)
4   KP v2 Dev                       0x0000cfc8 performerApp::setBankSettingsFromExternalFile(int) (performerApp.mm:2892)
5   KP v2 Dev                       0x00009862 performerApp::setup() (performerApp.mm:141)
6   KP v2 Dev                       0x00347750 Poco::PriorityDelegate<ofBaseApp, ofEventArgs, false>::notify(void const*, ofEventArgs&) (PriorityDelegate.h:168)
7   KP v2 Dev                       0x002e5dfa Poco::AbstractEvent<ofEventArgs, Poco::PriorityStrategy<ofEventArgs, Poco::AbstractPriorityDelegate<ofEventArgs> >, Poco::AbstractPriorityDelegate<ofEventArgs>, Poco::FastMutex>::notify(void const*, ofEventArgs&) (PriorityStrategy.h:81)
8   KP v2 Dev                       0x002e31a0 ofNotifySetup() (ofEventUtils.h:172)
9   KP v2 Dev                       0x00341246 -[ofxiOSEAGLView setup] (ofxiOSEAGLView.mm:0)
10  KP v2 Dev                       0x003498dc -[ofxiOSViewController viewDidLoad] (ofxiOSViewController.mm:54)
11  UIKit                           0x32c78c84 -[UIViewController view] + 160
12  UIKit                           0x32c7745a -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 38
13  UIKit                           0x32dfb774 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 332
14  KP v2 Dev                       0x00348706 -[ofxiOSAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] (ofxiOSAppDelegate.mm:170)
15  UIKit                           0x32c77cfa -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1262
16  UIKit                           0x32c717d6 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 402
17  UIKit                           0x32c3fabc -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1004
18  UIKit                           0x32c3f560 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
19  UIKit                           0x32c3ef34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
20  GraphicsServices                0x33231224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3551351c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
22  CoreFoundation                  0x355134be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3551230c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3549549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
25  CoreFoundation                  0x35495366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
26  UIKit                           0x32c70864 -[UIApplication _run] + 544
27  UIKit                           0x32c6dcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
28  KP v2 Dev                       0x00340600 ofAppiOSWindow::startAppWithDelegate(std::string) (ofAppiOSWindow.mm:96)
29  KP v2 Dev                       0x0034047e ofAppiOSWindow::runAppViaInfiniteLoop(ofBaseApp*) (ofAppiOSWindow.mm:84)
30  KP v2 Dev                       0x002dce9e ofRunApp(ofBaseApp*) (ofAppRunner.cpp:137)
31  KP v2 Dev                       0x00008f10 main (main.mm:32)
32  KP v2 Dev                       0x00008e00 start + 32
```

Here is the crash log using -Os:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x54442d1c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x36b6ab90 std::ios_base::_M_call_callbacks(std::ios_base::event) + 88
1   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x36b6ae48 std::ios_base::~ios_base() + 20
2   KP v2 Dev                       0x00031d38 std::string ofToString<int>(int const&) (basic_ios.h:268)
3   KP v2 Dev                       0x000593f4 BankData (BankData.mm:27)
4   KP v2 Dev                       0x00058bf2 ConfigData::init(int) (ConfigData.mm:28)
5   KP v2 Dev                       0x0000c082 performerApp::setup() (performerApp.mm:52)
6   KP v2 Dev                       0x00343700 Poco::PriorityDelegate<ofBaseApp, ofEventArgs, false>::notify(void const*, ofEventArgs&) (PriorityDelegate.h:168)
7   KP v2 Dev                       0x002e1daa Poco::AbstractEvent<ofEventArgs, Poco::PriorityStrategy<ofEventArgs, Poco::AbstractPriorityDelegate<ofEventArgs> >, Poco::AbstractPriorityDelegate<ofEventArgs>, Poco::FastMutex>::notify(void const*, ofEventArgs&) (PriorityStrategy.h:81)
8   KP v2 Dev                       0x002df150 ofNotifySetup() (ofEventUtils.h:172)
9   KP v2 Dev                       0x0033d1f6 -[ofxiOSEAGLView setup] (ofxiOSEAGLView.mm:0)
10  KP v2 Dev                       0x0034588c -[ofxiOSViewController viewDidLoad] (ofxiOSViewController.mm:54)
11  UIKit                           0x32c78c84 -[UIViewController view] + 160
12  UIKit                           0x32c7745a -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 38
13  UIKit                           0x32dfb774 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 332
14  KP v2 Dev                       0x003446b6 -[ofxiOSAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] (ofxiOSAppDelegate.mm:170)
15  UIKit                           0x32c77cfa -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1262
16  UIKit                           0x32c717d6 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 402
17  UIKit                           0x32c3fabc -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1004
18  UIKit                           0x32c3f560 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 48
19  UIKit                           0x32c3ef34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820
20  GraphicsServices                0x33231224 PurpleEventCallback + 876
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3551351c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
22  CoreFoundation                  0x355134be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3551230c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3549549e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
25  CoreFoundation                  0x35495366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
26  UIKit                           0x32c70864 -[UIApplication _run] + 544
27  UIKit                           0x32c6dcce UIApplicationMain + 1074
28  KP v2 Dev                       0x0033c5b0 ofAppiOSWindow::startAppWithDelegate(std::string) (ofAppiOSWindow.mm:96)
29  KP v2 Dev                       0x0033c42e ofAppiOSWindow::runAppViaInfiniteLoop(ofBaseApp*) (ofAppiOSWindow.mm:84)
30  KP v2 Dev                       0x002d8e4e ofRunApp(ofBaseApp*) (ofAppRunner.cpp:137)
31  KP v2 Dev                       0x0000bbe0 main (main.mm:32)
32  KP v2 Dev                       0x0000bad0 start + 32
```

Comment: Please provide a full symbolicated example crash report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that it was an Xcode bug. Fixed with Xcode 5.1.1.

From the Xcode release log:

> Resolved Issues: Crash in compiled code when targeting iOS 5.1.1
>   (16485980)

Answer (score 2):

Often when something crashes at higher optimizations but not at -O0 it means you are either using a variable that is uninitialized, or using an object after it has been freed.  At -O0 lots of data is left sitting around after it is done with, whereas at higher optimizations it is more aggressively reused.  The Xcode static analyzer is very handy for finding uninitialized variable use.  And running with Guard Malloc (settable in the Diagnostics pane of the Xcode Run scheme) will catch use after free at the point where it occurs, rather than sometime much further downstream.

Comment: I tried with Guard Malloc enabled, but got a `dyld: could not load inserted library: /usr/lib/libgmalloc.dylib` error. From searching Stack Overflow, looks like Guard Malloc is only available for simulator profiling, not on the device. And Xcode5 only supports back to iOS6.0 simulator not iOS5, which is where the crash happens.

Comment: @Jim Ingham...   Your comments re: the memory reuse seems to be the most plausible explanation for some non-compiler-bug-related crashes, when running with different optimization levels.....